# Validación form request GlobalScope

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente situación espero me puedan orientar. Tengo una función global que uso en cada modelo para controlar la información que puede ver y administrar cada usuario de acuerdo a su `id`.

```
static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) {

if (auth()->user()->status=="User_access") {

return $builder->where('user_id', auth()->id()); } }

//En cada modelo la uso.

class Category extends Model
{

  use Multitenantable;
}
```

De está manera cada usuario solo administra la información que le corresponde.
Lo que deseo hacer es que el nombre de una categoría sea único en todo el sistema; sin embargo el sistema solo valida los campos nombres de categoría únicos que hallan sido creados por cada usuario; debido a que el modelo siempre valida `return $builder->where('user_id', auth()->id())`. Estoy usando la clase `form request` y quisiera saber como validar nombres únicos de categorías que existan en todo el sistema independientemente de cual usuario los halla creado.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar

```
withoutGlobalScopes();
```

Con este ignoras los global scopes, si solo deseas ignorar el globalScope que mencionas utilizas

```
withoutGlobalScope(MiScope::class);
```

Comment: Deseo ignorar, solo cuando voy a validar con la clase form request los campos únicos .

Comment: Esto te permite ignorar cuando realizas tu query con eloquent para todas las demás sigue funcionando tu global scope

Comment: Genial, justo lo que buscaba; gracias amigo